Best Practices: Converting (print) footnotes to web
I am the publisher/editor/curator of an electronic magazine/website. Occasionally, I receive submissions for publication that have footnotes; in the PDF, which is specifically intended to mimic a print publication, those footnotes remain footnotes.
After publication in the PDF, I insert the articles into the website as “standard” HTML pages. However, I am not sure what the best practice for handling the footnotes would be:

Keep them as footnotes/endnotes - that is, a superscripted number in the body, and a corresponding numbered text block at the end of the article
Convert them into small sidebars at the location where the note occurs
Convert them into “tooltips” in-line in the text.

Note that where the footnote is simply a reference to another website (URL), I convert the footnote into a link to the URL on the footnoted text; it is other, non-linking footnotes that I am uncertain of how best to handle.

I think you should understand the limitations of a print publication as opposed to the advantages of an online publication.
Footnotes with clarification at the end are a solution for a printed publication, since the text on one page does not leave enough space for clarifications. While in an online publication, the space is practically infinite. I would rule out option 1 based on the possibilities that online development offers.
Regarding options 2 and 3, there are pros and cons:

A "static" sidebar forces you to create extra space for notes, which
takes up space on pages.
A tooltip determines the size of the note. If it is a line of text it
may be correct, but if it is a block of text, the tooltip stops being
such and becomes a text window.

I would study the option of a dynamic lateral sidebar, which appears/disappears through a button activated every time the user wants it and each footnote with a highlight in the corresponding text.




I'd have to check to be certain (the magazine has gone through over 100 issues), but I don't think there have been many footnotes that have run to as many as five lines of text (3.5" columns, 9pt text). I don't think a tooltip would be considered to have 'morphed' into a text window for any past footnotes.

That said, the sliding sidebar is an interesting idea; can you point me to some resources on how to do this?
